# Weird behaviour Tree inside ui:repeat or ice:panelseries

Tags: jsf, tree, jsf-2, icefaces

So i basicly have a tree inside a collapsible and is iterating with a ui:repeat or ice:panelSeries because they pretty much have the same structure

```
<ui:repeat value="#{navigationBean.navigationPanels}" var="panel"  >
        <ice:panelCollapsible immediate="true" expanded="#{panel.expanded}" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <ice:panelGroup>
                    <ice:outputText value="#{panel.title}" />
                </ice:panelGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <ice:panelGroup styleClass="treeContainer">
                <ice:tree id="tree" value="#{panel.treeModel}" var="item"
                    hideRootNode="true" hideNavigation="true" 
                    imageDir="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/xmlhttp/css/xp/css-images/">
                    <ice:treeNode>
                        <f:facet name="icon">
                            <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                <h:graphicImage
                                    value="#{userPreferences.imageDirectory}/#{item.userObject.icon}" />
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="content">
                            <ice:panelGroup style="display: inline">
                                <ice:outputLink value="#{item.userObject.url}">
                                    <ice:outputText styleClass="treeNode" value="#{item.userObject.text}" />
                                </ice:outputLink>
                            </ice:panelGroup>
                        </f:facet>
                    </ice:treeNode>
                </ice:tree>
            </ice:panelGroup>
        </ice:panelCollapsible>
        </ui:repeat>
```

The problem is that when i expand or collapse the panel gives me an awful error here is the stack:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitRows(Tree.java:1447)
    at com.icesoft.faces.component.tree.Tree.visitTree(Tree.java:1402)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.component.UIRepeat.visitTree(UIRepeat.java:606)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:331)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1487)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.deliverPostRestoreStateEvent(RestoreViewPhase.java:258)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:245)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:97)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:114)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:308)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea why it could be behaving like this??

Answer (score 0):

According to the [source](http://sventon.icefaces.org/svn/showfile.svn?name=repo&revision=HEAD&path=/icefaces2/trunk/icefaces/compat/components/src/main/java/com/icesoft/faces/component/tree/Tree.java), `#{panel.treeModel}` evaluates to null.

Try `<ice:tree rendered="#{panel.treeModel != null} ...`, and see what happens.

Comment: nothing i tried and also with rendered="#{not empty panel.treeModel}" but still facing the same annoying error!!

Comment: as i said this only happened with ui:series or ice:panelSeries because i manually by setting the arrays index of the list navigationPanels , set my beans and it work nicely!!

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the the problem does not occur at rendering. It could occur while building the server side component tree. On such cases you have to make sure that the xml tag `<ice:tree../>` is not parsed at all.

So try:

```
<c:if test="#{not empty panel.treeModel}"> <ice:tree ../> </c:if>
```

This is not working in all cases. So give it a try :-)